# RSS feed not updating using feeds module

Tags: 7, feeds, updating

I have an RSS feed that has not been updated after the initial import. I actually managed to get it to update once using cron, but even that has since stopped working. Looking at the original feed, I see it is being updated, but I'm not getting the updates on my site.

My feed importer settings are as follows:

- It is attached to a specific content type
- The minimum refresh period is 15 minutes
- The option "Import on submission" is checked
- The fetcher is "HTTP"
- The parser is set to "common syndication parser"
- The processor is "node processor"
- I respecify the content type in node processor settings
- The input format is the default one
- "Expire nodes" is set to "never"
- "Update existing nodes" is set to "Update existing nodes (slower than replacing them)"

Is there anything else I need to do, maybe configure something in Job Scheduler? I couldn't find a UI for it.

EDIT: Upon checking `admin/reports/dblog` as per Jeremy's suggestion I found the following error:

> Download of failed with code -1003.

Does anyone know what this means or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at /admin/reports/status does it say that cron is running?

If cron is running then looking at the watchdog entries (
admin/reports/dblog) around the time it is running may give you an insight.

If that dosn't work then you may have to start putting debug into the modules code to work out what is going wrong.

Comment: Yes, right now it says Last run "35 min 4 sec ago"...

Comment: Edited question with some more ideas.

Comment: Seeing as the problem turned out to be very specific and was not resolved in any conventional way, I will go with this response as at least it did offer helpful debugging advice. Thanks!